# Download link for SQL Server 2008 Developer edition and SQL Server 2008 Standard edition?

Tags: sql-server, windows-xp-sp3

I want to download SQL Server 2008 Developer edition and SQL Server 2008 Standard edition in Microsoft's web site but I can't find the link to download the iso image.

Can you help me to find the link?

Comment: Only the Express edition is available for free

Answer (score 2):

Here is an explanation why you can't find the Developer Edition link and the link to download Express Edition.
[sql-server-2008-download-copy-of-developer-edition-for-free-is-myth](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/23/sql-server-2008-download-copy-of-developer-edition-for-free-is-myth/)